# File download not working page refresh

Tags: php

I am trying to use PHP to force a download at the click of a button. But nothing happens each time the download button is clicked apart from page reload.

```
if(isset($_GET['download'])){

    try {
        $sql = 'SELECT file_name, file_type FROM files WHERE id = :id';
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':id', $_GET['file_id']);
        $s->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error = 'download error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        include 'error.php';
        exit();
    }

    $file = $s->fetch();
    if(!$file){
        $error = 'File not found!: ' . $e->getMessage();
        include 'error.php';
        exit();
    }

    $filename = $file['file_name'];
    $mimetype = $file['file_type'];
    $filedata = "users/$firstname/".$_POST['file_name'];
    $disposition = 'inline';

    header('Content-length: ' . strlen($filedata));
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-disposition: $disposition; filename=$filedata");

    echo readfile($filedata);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way of forcing a download is:

```
header('Location: *Your path to download file*');
```

But that is just what I think, and this answer might be really unhelpful to you...